# Windows Server 2019 OpenSSH SFTP Server Won't Authenticate Users Anymore (Connection Reset)

Tags: windows, sftp

I am running Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763 on Azure and I had SFTP working just fine until EITHER a recent update and reboot on Windows OR an SFTP username (the "vendor1" user) password change on ActiveDirectory clobbered this working install of OpenSSH.

Now when attempting to SFTP from a client machine, all I get is,

> Connection reset by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22
>
> Connection closed

What could be wrong? Has anyone else experienced this and solved it?

Here's my sshd_config file, which was working:

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
Banner F:\SFTP-Welcome.txt
#Banner /SFTP-Welcome.txt

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

#Match Group administrators
#       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys

#DenyGroups company\vendors company\auditors
#AllowGroups company\administrators

Match Group vendors
   ChrootDirectory F:\Vendors
   #ChrootDirectory F:\Vendors\%u
   #ChrootDirectory %h
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   X11Forwarding no
   AllowTcpForwarding no

# no default banner path
#Banner F:\Vendors\SFTP-Welcome.txt
#Banner /SFTP-Welcome.txt
```

Using the -v (verbose) option in my SFTP command (sftp -v vendor1@its.my.ip.addr) yields:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\mylocalusername/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\mylocalusername/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\mylocalusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\mylocalusername/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\mylocalusername/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
vendor1@its.my.ip.addrr's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to its.my.ip.addrr ([its.my.ip.addrr]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
Connection reset by its.my.ip.addrr port 22
Connection closed
```

That user "mylocalusername" is my local client PC Windows login name.

Comment: How about looking in the server logs? Is your firewall filtering / blocking the port 22 requests?

Comment: In PowerShell, I ran: Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *ssh*
Here are the results:

Name                  : OpenSSH-Server-In-TCP
DisplayName           : OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)
Description           : Inbound rule for OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)
DisplayGroup          : OpenSSH Server
Group                 : OpenSSH Server
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Any
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False

Comment: Basically, the firewall seems fine. Uncommenting the log lines in the sshd_config file fields nothing in the C:\ProgramData\ssh\logs folder. Checking the Event Viewer now....

Comment: In the Event Viewer's Application and Services Log, inside OpenSSH | Operational, I see sshd: Accepted password for vendor1 from its.my.ip.addr port 11678 ssh2....not sure why the port is different but it looks like it's recognizing me.

Comment: It's the `source port` of the connection, it won't be `22`. Are outbound connections from sshd allowed in your firewall? You only listed inbound. Check the clients verbose message as well, e. g.: `ssh -v user@host`

Comment: I went ahead and added a new outbound rule, although I never had to before. No change. I'll append the results of my verbose option to the main post.

Comment: Also, I just remembered another recent change is a password reset to my vendor1 user in ActiveDirectory. However it doesn't seem that affected SFTP authentication, because the verbose output says, "debug1: Authentication succeeded (password). Authenticated to its.my.ip.addrr ([its.my.ip.addrr]:22)."

Comment: Could you run the sshd on Windows in debug mode and connect? E.g. `sshd.exe -ddd`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93138/discussion-between-lenniey-and-shieldofsalvation).

Comment: Will that allow future readers to see it and still benefit from this?

Comment: yes: https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention Also, if it leads to an answer, it should be posted as an answer. That will definitely keep it.

Comment: I gave up on this and ended up switching my OpenSSH service to a paid SolarWinds Serv-U subscription. This runs our SFTP service now. Serv-U also provides me with a separate FTPS server which my clients have preferred over SFTP at this point. We haven't looked back since.